# Por que no me muestra los datos con ajax tampoco me sale error phpmysql

Tags: php, json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <section class="content-header">
  <h1>
    Administrar Productos
  </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="inicio"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> 
      Inicio</a></li>
     <li class="active">Administrar Productos</li>
    </ol>
  </section>
 <section class="content">
 <div class="box">
   <div class="box-header with-border">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data- 
    target="#modalAgregarProducto">
        Agregar Producto
    </button>
 </div>
 <div class="box-body">
 <table class=" table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive 
  tablaProductos" width="100%">
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th style="width:10px">#</th>
        <th>Imagen</th>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Descripcíon</th>
        <th>Categorias</th>
        <th>Stock</th>  
        <th>Precio De compra</th>
        <th>Precio De venta</th>
        <th>Agregado</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>  
     </tr>
     </thead>
      <!-- <tbody>
     <?php
     $item = null;
     $valor = null;
     $productos = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarProductos($item, 
     $valor);

      foreach ($productos as $key => $value) {
          
      echo '<tr>
      <td>'.($key+1).'</td>
       <td><img src="vistas/img/productos/default/anonymous.png"class="img-thumbnail" width="40px"></td>
               <td>'.$value["codigo"].'</td>
              <td>'.$value["descripcion"].'</td>';

               $item = "id";
               $valor = $value["id_categoria"];
               $categoria = ControladorCategorias::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);  

         echo '<td>'.$categoria["categoria"].'</td>
               <td>'.$value["stock"].'</td>
               <td>$'.$value["precio_compra"].'</td>
               <td>$'.$value["precio_venta"].'</td>
               <td>'.$value["fecha"].'</td>
               

              <td>
          
               <div class="btn-group">

              <button class=" btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>

            <button class=" btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            
          </div>

        </td>

      </tr>';
        }

        ?>  

      </tbody> -->

    </table>

    </div>
    
  </div>
  

   </section>

  </div>
  {  =====================================
      MODAL AGREGAR PRODUCTO
   ========================================= }


      <div id="modalAgregarProducto" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

        <div class="modal-dialog">


       <div class="modal-content">

       <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     { =====================================
      {CABEZA DEL MODAL}
     ========================================= }

  <div class="modal-header" style="background:#3c8dbc; color:white">

    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

    <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar Producto</h4>

  </div>

    =====================================
              CUERPO DEL MODAL
     ========================================= 

  <div class="modal-body">

   <div class="box-body">

    <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL CODIGO-->

    <div class="form-group">
     
     <div class="input-group">
       
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-code"></i></span>

       <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoCodigo" placeholder="Ingrese     Código" required>

     </div>

     </div>

   <!-- ENTRADA PARA LA DESCRIPCION-->

    <div class="form-group">
     
     <div class="input-group">
       
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i></span>

       <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevaDescripcion" placeholder="Ingrese Descripción" required>

   </div>

     </div>
    
     <!-- ENTRADA PARA SELECCIONAR CATEGORIA-->

     <div class="form-group">
     
   >  <div class="input-group">
       
   >    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-th"></i></span>

    >   <select class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevaCategoria" >
        
    >    <option value="">Selecionar Perfil</option>

    >    <option value="Taladros">Taladros</option>

    >    <option value="Andamios">Andamios</option>

    >    <option value="Equipos para la contrucíon">Equipos para la contrucíon</option>

        
    >   </select>

    >   </div>

   >  </div>

   >   <!-- ENTRADA PARA STOCK-->

 >   <div class="form-group">
     
  >   <div class="input-group">
       
    >   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>

   >    <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoStock" min="0"  >placeholder="STOCK" required>

    >   </div>

   >  </div>

    >  <!-- ENTRADA PARA PRECIO COMPRA-->

   > <div class="form-group row">

   >   <div class="col-xs-6">
     
   >  <div class="input-group">
       
   >    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></span>

    >   <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoPrecioCompra" min="0" >placeholder="Precio De Compra" required>

     >  </div>    

     >  </div>     

    > <!-- ENTRADA PARA PRECIO VENTA-->

     > <div class="col-xs-6">
           
    > <div class="input-group">         
       
     >  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></span>

     >  <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoPrecioVenta" min="0" >placeholder="Precio De Venta" required>

>            </div>

>           <br>

>          <!-- CHECKBOX PARA PORCENTAJE-->

 >         <div class="col-xs-6">
            
  >          <div class=" form-group">
              
   >           <label>

    >            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal porcentaje" checked>
     >           Utilizar porcentaje
    >          </label>

   >         </div>

          </div>

          <!-- ENTRADA PARA PORCENTAJE-->

          <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding:0">
            
            <div class="input-group">
              
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg nuevoPorcentaje" min="0" value="40" required>

            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-percent"></i></span>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

     </div>

     <!-- ENTRADA PARA SUBIR FOTO-->

     <div class="form-group">
     
     <div class="panel">SUBIR IMAGEN</div>

     <input type="file" id="nuevaImagen" name="nuevaImagen">

     <p class="help-block">Peso maximo de la imagen 2 MB</p>

     <img src="vistas/img/productos/default/anonymous.png" class="img-thumbnail" width="100px">

     </div>

   </div>

  </div>

     =====================================
      PIE DEL PAGINA DEL MODAL
     ========================================= 

  <div class="modal-footer">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-defaul pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Producto</button>

  </div>

  <?php 

  $crearUsuario = new ControladorUsuarios();
  $crearUsuario -> ctrCrearUsuario();

  ?>

  </form>

</div>

   </div>
  </div>
```

clase producto.js
Aqui llamo al dataTable

```
    /=============================================
        = CARGAR LA TABLA DINAMICA DE PRODUCTOS =
   =============================================/

    $.ajax({

 url:"ajax/datatable-productos.ajax.php",
 success:function(respuesta){
      console.log("respuesta", respuesta);

 }
  })

  $('.tablaProductos').DataTable({
 "ajax": "ajax/datatable-productos.ajax.php"
       });
```

clase datatable-productos.ajax.php
esta es la clase que me tendria qwue traer los datos de la base

```
<?php

    require_once "../controladores/productos.controlador.php";
    require_once "../modelos/productos.modelo.php";

    require_once "../controladores/categorias.controlador.php";
    require_once "../modelos/categorias.modelo.php";

       class TablaProductos{

     /=============================================
       = MOSTRAR LA TABLA DE PRODUCTOS =
     =============================================/
public function mostrarTablaProductos(){

  $item = null;
  $valor =null;

  $productos = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarProductos($item,$valor);

  
  $botones= "<div class='btn-group'>
           <button class=' btn btn-warning'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button>
            <button class=' btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button></div>";

  $datosJson = ' {
 "data": [';

 for ($i=0; $i < count($productos) ; $i++) { 
   
  $imagen = "<img src ='".$productos[$i]["imagen"]."' width='40px'>";       

   $datosJson .='[
  "'.($i+1).'",
  "'.$imagen.'",
  "'.$productos[$i]["codigo"].'",
  "'.$productos[$i]["descripcion"].'",
  
  "'.$productos[$i]["stock"].'",
  "'.$productos[$i]["precio_compra"].'",
  "'.$productos[$i]["precio_venta"].'",
  "'.$productos[$i]["fecha"].'",
  "'.$botones.'"
],';
 }

   $datosJson = substr($datosJson,0,-1);
    $datosJson .= ']}'; 

   echo $datosJson;

             
      }
   }
     /=============================================
            = ACTIVAR TABLA DE PRODUCTOS =
       =============================================/
      $activarProductos = new TablaProductos();
      $activarProductos -> mostrarTablaProductos();
```

Comment: no le as especificado nunca que tipo de contenido es el que recibe y no sabe como debe manejarlo!

Comment: en donde y domo deberia hacer eso ?

Answer (score 0):

la solucion es que ene le formulario principal me olvide de llamar a la clase producto.js